# How to remove Games on Fedora 14?

Tags: linux, fedora, fedora-13

While installing the fedora desktop I had unchecked the Games and Entertainment section but I can still see the same Games options available in the menu.

I tried checking the same in the Add/Remove Programs but I was not able to get the option for uninstalling the same.

Games which are present are: AisleRiot Solitaire, lagno, Mines and Sudoku

I would like to delete the games options available. Can someone help me doing the same?

Comment: It would help to know what is in the menu.

Comment: If you're using Gnome, you could edit the menu and hide the section. Otherwise search for the packages and remove them (the section itself is not a package).

Comment: The menu consists of a tab Games > AisleRiot, Solitaire, lagno, Mines and Sudoku are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the Games and Entertainment section there were games that were present in the gnome-games section which I successfully removed games like AisleRiot Solitaire, lagno, Mines and Sudoku which were present.

Answer (score 0):

Using yumex to remove games only gave me more games to remove (Fed 20/kde). I resorted to Apper to identify apps and supporting libraries. Then I used yum remove xxx to do the actual removal, one app and library at a time.